# Запись в таблицу word. Почему не работает?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Беру шаблонную строку:
[image: шаблон]
Добавляю ещё 3 таких строки к этой таблице:

```
    XWPFTableRow templateRow = bodyTbl.getRow(0);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        bodyTbl.addRow(templateRow);
        
    }
```

И пытаюсь заменить текст в ячейках на свой:

```
    List<XWPFTableRow> rows = bodyTbl.getRows();
    
    System.out.println("rows " + rows.size());
    
    int i = -1;
    for(XWPFTableRow row : rows) {
        
        i++;
        
        List<XWPFTableCell> cells = row.getTableCells();
        
        for(XWPFTableCell cell : cells) {
            
            XWPFRun runCell = cell.getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0);
            
            runCell.setText(i + " QQQ", 0);
            
        }
    }
```

В результате работа идет только с первой строкой...
[image: результат]
Почему так? Как мне заменить $_ в таблице во всех ячейках на свои значения?
Apache POI 3.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавать нужно как-то так.

```
/** Получим перечень шаблонов
 * @param table - таблица
 * @return - возвращаем перечень шаблонов
 */
private static List<String> createTemplate(XWPFTable table){

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    //берем шаблонные значения с первой строки таблицы
    List<XWPFTableCell> cells = table.getRow(0).getTableCells();
    //и заполняем коллекцию
    for(XWPFTableCell cell : cells) {

        result.add(cell.getText());
    }

    return result;
}

/** Создаем строку в таблице и заполняем шаблонами
 * @param tempList - шаблоны
 * @param table - таблица
 */
private static void createRow(List<String> tempList, XWPFTable table) {

    //создаём новую строку
    XWPFTableRow newTemplateRow = table.createRow();

    //получаем все ячейки
    List<XWPFTableCell> cells = newTemplateRow.getTableCells();

    for(int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {

        //получаем ячейку
        XWPFTableCell cell = cells.get(i);
        //получаем параграф
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.getParagraphArray(0);
        //получаем строку
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

        //устанавливаем размер шрифта, шрифт, положение в ячейке
        run.setFontSize(10);
        run.setFontFamily("Courier New");
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

        run.setText(tempList.get(i), 0);
    }
}
```